# Ads not showing inbetween post on my Blogger blog

Tags: blogger

Having been trying to add my Google AdSense code inbetween post body on my Blogger but the moment I add it and navigate back to check it... It won't display afs.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1. First thing you need to do is to parse the AdSense code and convert it to plain text (look in google for adsense script to text converter). Then go to "Template", click on the "Edit HTML" button and click anywhere inside the code area to search using CTRL + F keys for this tag:

```html
<data:post.body/>
```

Note: you may find it several times, but you need to stop at the second one. Or, if you can't see any changes, test the third one.
Step 2. Replace  with this code:

```html
<div expr:id='"adsmiddle1" + data:post.id'></div>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "item"'>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;static_page&quot;'>
<div style="clear:both; margin:10px 0">
<!-- Add here the code of your ad -->
</div>
</b:if>
</b:if>
<div expr:id='"adsmiddle2" + data:post.id'>
<data:post.body/>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var obj0=document.getElementById("adsmiddle1<data:post.id/>");
var obj1=document.getElementById("adsmiddle2<data:post.id/>");
var s=obj1.innerHTML;
var r=s.search(/\x3C!-- adsense --\x3E/igm);
if(r>0) {obj0.innerHTML=s.substr(0,r);obj1.innerHTML=s.substr(r+16);}
</script>
```

Step 3. Add the converted Adsense code on where you see the  annotation, then save the changes by clicking on the "Save template" button.

Note: For centering the ads, add the  tags before and after the AdSense code, like this:

```html
<div style="clear:both; margin:10px 0">
<center> 
<!-- Add here the code of your ad -->
</center>
</div>
```

Adding the AdSense annotation to display the ad
Step 4. When you create a New Post, add this annotation inside the "HTML" section to where you want the Google AdSense ads to appear:

```html
<!-- adsense -->
```

For example:

```html
This is a demo text. This is a demo text. This is a demo text. This is a demo text. This is a demo text. This is a demo text. This is a demo text. This is a demo text. This is a demo text. This is a demo text.<br /><br /> <!-- adsense -->This is a demo text. This is a demo text. This is a demo text. This is a demo text. This is a demo text. This is a demo text. This is a demo text. This is a demo text. This is a demo text. This is a demo text.
```

I really hope this solution will help you